# Selectize.js and jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, selectize.js

I'm trying to validate a form that uses the [**Selectize.js**](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) to select and [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin for validation.

I can not make it work. The script validates the input fields, but not the select:

```
<form id="test" method="post" action="#">
Name: <input name="name" type="text">

<select name="person" id="select-beast" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>n>
</select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-12 col-lg-12">Go</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#select-beast').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'text'
});
    

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#test").validate({
    errorElement: 'label',
    errorClass: 'error',
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        person: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Insert name.",
        person: "Insert person.",
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/8nVqS/**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason is that jQuery.validation plugin will ignore all hidden element when validating by default.

And Selectize.js will hide the given jQuery object, So your name field will run validate but person field will not.

Solution, please reference this gist: [How to validate selectize.js comboboxes with the jQuery validation plugin](https://gist.github.com/yannleretaille/8498983)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Need some more support

Answer (score 8):

The answers provided above aren't working with selectize.js **v0.12.3** or greater.

That is happening due to the fact that the required attribute is removed from the select in ***refreshValidityState*** function - see https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/commit/abc8a560a8335a017790c2a799925cc123670bfc

A quick fix for this is to add the selects that are **required** in the rules array of the validation options object.

Example:

```
var validator = $("#form").validate({
            ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',
            rules: {
                "select-name-here": "required",
                "select-name-here2": "required"
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using

ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input',

and it works for me.

Comment: Where does that go?

Comment: $("#test").validate({ ignore:IT_WILL_BE_HERE });